# How do I pull tiles from a custom OSM tile server? My URL string doesn't seem to be working

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, osmdroid

We have a custom OSM tile server set up on AWS and pointed to a subdomain URL.  If I type the URL in a browser, the map appears fine.

Now I need to access the tile server, both with Leaflet and OSMDROID (website and app).  But in neither case do the  map images appear.  Given the similarity in how a tile server is called, I think I am making the same mistake for both.  My code for Leaflet is:

```
map = L.map('map_canvas').setView([0, 30], 11);
L.tileLayer('https://subdomain.mydomain.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
```

Any suggestions?  Or someplace else where I should be looking to correct this?  Using the default OSM public map works for both.

Thanks

Comment: Any errors on your browser's console?

Comment: No errors.. it acts like a map (pins work for example), but the raster files aren't showing.

Comment: Using the network monitor in the browser's tools, are the tiles being requested over the network?

Comment: Looks like requests went out for the png files, but came back with 404 errors.

Comment: But you said that if you type the URL in the browser, the tile loads. Are the tile URLs that Leaflet requests any different than the ones which work?

Comment: OK, I just figured it out, thanks to you pointing me in the right direction!  I will answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Leaflet and OSMDroid seem to be requesting pre-rendered tiles, and the generic url was giving a 404 error for each specific tile that was unsuccessfully requested.  I just had to figure out the right path for where they were.  This code now works:

```
map = L.map('map_canvas').setView([0, 30], 11);
L.tileLayer('https://subdomain.mydomain.com/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
```